# How to use a Postgrex Extension?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to use the tsvector extension provided by [Postgrex](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex/blob/master/lib/postgrex/extensions/tsvector.ex). But how do I actually use this in my Phoeinx project? Here is my setup in dev.exs

```
config :project, Project.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "project_dev",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool_size: 10,
  extensions: [{Postgrex.Extensions.TSVector}]
```

This is the schema

```
  schema "branches" do
    field :address, :string
    field :tags, {:array, :string}
    field :document, Postgrex.Extensions.TSVector

    belongs_to :bank, Bank

    timestamps()
  end
```

Should this not give me a new type `TSVector`? I am getting the following error

```
** (ArgumentError) invalid or unknown type Postgrex.Extensions.TSVector for field :document
```

**Update**

I tried setting the schema to the following

```
field :document, {:array, Postgrex.Lexeme}
```

On retriving value from the database I get the following error
`** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Postgrex.Lexeme.type/0 is undefined or private`

Comment: Show your schema, please. I expect you have there smth like `field :document, TSVector` while it should be fully qualified `field :document, Postgrex.Extensions.TSVector`.

Comment: @mudasobwa added

Comment: Would you mind to try `:tsvector` as field type (exactly in your migration.).

Comment: According to [Ecto Postgres docs](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex#data-representation), it should be `field :document, {:array, Postgrex.Lexeme}`.

Comment: Used the above, now getting `** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Postgrex.Lexeme.type/0 is undefined or private`

Comment: That is strange [due to this](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex/blob/af5800ec978ebb2a319daaa47f183a08bdec550a/lib/postgrex/builtins.ex#L192). Maybe it should be `field :document, {:array, %Postgrex.Lexeme{}}`? Unlikely, though.

Comment: Wont compile. It seems an Ecto type need to define an `info` function.

Comment: Or an [explicit type definition](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex#extensions).

Comment: Could you make it work? I am also struggling to query tsvector field in postgresql. Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @AbhayPS check this https://www.reddit.com/r/elixir/comments/72z762/how_to_use_postgrex_extension_to_create_an_ecto/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. The `tsvector` extension is included/loaded by default with Postgrex after this pull request: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex/pull/284, so it's not necessary to add any `:extensions` option to your `Project.Repo` configuration.

I created the column in a migration like this:

```
def change do
  alter table(:diagnoses) do
    add :search_tsvector, :tsvector
  end

  execute "UPDATE diagnoses SET search_tsvector = to_tsvector('english', concat_ws(' ', description, icd10_code))"

  create index(:diagnoses, [:search_tsvector], using: :gin)
end
```

After that, it turns out you can't simply add `:tsvector` to your module schema, since no `:tsvector` `Ecto` type exists (only the `Postgrex` type, because of the extension).

To use this new column in my schema, I needed to add a custom `Ecto` type with just the default boilerplate definition:

```
defmodule MyApp.Ecto.Types.TSVectorType do
  @behaviour Ecto.Type

  def type, do: :tsvector

  def cast(tsvector), do: {:ok, tsvector}

  def load(tsvector), do: {:ok, tsvector}

  def dump(tsvector), do: {:ok, tsvector}
end
```

After that, you can include this type in your module `schema`:

```
schema "diagnoses" do
  field :icd10_code, :string
  field :description, :string
  field :search_tsvector, MyApp.Ecto.Types.TSVectorType

  timestamps_with_deleted_at()
end
```

I implemented searching this `tsvector` field like this:

```
defp filter_by(query, :search_string, %{search_string: search_string} = args) do
  tsquery_string = StringHelpers.to_tsquery_string(search_string)

  from d in query,
    where: fragment("? @@ to_tsquery('english', ?)", d.search_tsvector, ^tsquery_string)
end
```